# Why is Robomongo returning an object from db.collection.distinct() instead of an array?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

Using the [example from the MongoDB reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/), I'd expect `db.inventory.distinct("dept");` to return an array `["A", "B"]`, and that's exactly what happens when I run this from the shell. Using Robomongo (on OS X) I instead get an object with name-value pairs, like so: `{ "0" :"A", "1": "B" }`.

This is the setup:

```
db.inventory.drop();
db.inventory.insert([
    { "_id": 1, "dept": "A", "item": { "sku": "111", "color": "red" },
    { "_id": 2, "dept": "A", "item": { "sku": "111", "color": "blue" },
    { "_id": 3, "dept": "B", "item": { "sku": "222", "color": "blue" },
    { "_id": 4, "dept": "A", "item": { "sku": "333", "color": "black" } 
]);
```

Why is Robomongo behaving different? Can I do anything about it?